# Calculate limit of $a_n(b - c_n^\frac{1}{m})$

Tags: limits

Let $m > 1$ be an integer.

I need to calculate the limit $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n(1 - c_n^{\frac{1}{m}}) $$

All I know is that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n(1 - c_n) = L > 0 \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} c_n = 1$$

How can I relate these latter limits to the former?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from $(1-x^m)=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots x^{m-1})$. Then

$$a_n(1-c_n)= a_n(1-c_n^{\frac1m})(1+c_n^{1/m}+c_n^{2/m} +\dots c_n^{(m-1)/{m}})$$ 
So

$$\frac{a_n(1-c_n)}{1+c_n^{1/m}+c_n^{2/m} +\dots c_n^{(m-1)/{m}}}= a_n(1-c_n^{\frac1m})$$

By taking $n\to \infty$, you'd find that the limit of the right hand side is $\frac{L}{m}$.

Comment: very nice solution!

Comment: You added one extra term in the denominator, I think.

Comment: @massiverisk: my bad, I have corrected it.